# xctest How to use data captured in one test method in another test method

Tags: xctest

In one test method I am calling an API and storing data to class property which I want to use in another test method as well.
But every time test method gets called, new instance of test class is allocated to it and hence class property initialises every time.

So is there any way to store the data to use it in other test methods? I don't want top use static data.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this fits to your problem...

for the first method do something like

```
var persistence: CoreDataPersistence?
override func setUp() {
    super.setUp()
    persistence = CoreDataPersistence()
}
```

You can also use XCTAssert... methods in the setUp method as you do in the test methods.

Then write your test methods as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Use Singleton class to hold this info, and not test class itself.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).